# Accessing Postgresql instance via Flask/ SQLAlchemy on GCP from my laptop

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I've created a flask app that connects to Postgresql via SQLAlchemy. I created a local DB and the application runs locally on my machine with no issues. I checked that the corresponding tables have been successfully created. I used the following configuration.

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql://postgres:abcdef@localhost:5432/mydb'
```

Now, I am trying to run the same Flask app from my laptop but to connect to a remote DB instance on GCP using the following configuration, but it's not working. I have already created a DB instance on GCP, enabled the necessary APIs and authorized access in my DB instance to the IP address of my laptop.

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:abcdef@/postgres?host=/cloudsql/project-1:us-central1:mydb'
```

Here is the error message that I receive:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/project-1:us-central1:mydb/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022)
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Any advice on the correct formatting of the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to connect to a DB instance on GCP is greatly appreciated. BTW, I've seen several online posts but none was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a while, I figured out away to do that and the correct configurations for SQLAlchemy instance is as follow.

```
PASSWORD=abc123              # Password of DB instance on GCP
PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS=123.345.67 # IP address of DB instance on GCP
DBNAME=mydb                  # Database name on GCP
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f'postgresql://postgres:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}/{DBNAME}'
```

If you need to connect to a MySQL instance, here is the correct configuration.

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]=  f'mysql://root:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}/{DBNAME}'
```

You may need to need to install mysqlclient, but the version that worked for me was 1.3.12.

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12
```

After I ran my Falsk App locally on my laptop, I checked the database on the GCP and the app actually populated the DB.